# Tests in Eclipse with Maven pass, but execution from Jenkins fails

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins

Hi i am very new to eclipse, maven, jenkins. i have an eclipse project. with the following code:

```
package leantesting; 
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import junit.framework.*;

import com.hp.lft.sdk.*;
import com.hp.lft.sdk.web.*;
import com.hp.lft.sdk.web.Browser;
import com.hp.lft.sdk.web.BrowserFactory;
import com.hp.lft.sdk.web.BrowserType;
import com.hp.lft.sdk.web.EditFieldDescription;
import com.hp.lft.verifications.*;


import unittesting.*;

public class LeanFtTest extends UnitTestClassBase {

    public LeanFtTest() {
        //Change this constructor to private if you supply your own public constructor
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        instance = new LeanFtTest();
        globalSetup(LeanFtTest.class);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        globalTearDown();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void Chrome() throws GeneralLeanFtException {
        Crossbrowser(BrowserType.CHROME);

    }

    @Test
    public void Firefox() throws GeneralLeanFtException {
        Crossbrowser(BrowserType.FIREFOX);

    }
    @Test
    public void InternetExplorer() throws GeneralLeanFtException {
        Crossbrowser(BrowserType.INTERNET_EXPLORER);

    }

    public void Crossbrowser(BrowserType pbrowser) throws GeneralLeanFtException {

        Browser browser = BrowserFactory.launch(pbrowser);

        browser.navigate("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");

        browser.describe(EditField.class, new EditFieldDescription.Builder()
                .tagName("INPUT").name("userName").build()).setValue("Amir");
        browser.describe(EditField.class, new EditFieldDescription.Builder()
                .type("password").tagName("INPUT").name("password").build()).setSecure("58a30b6a0708b8909633e81f");
        browser.describe(Image.class, new ImageDescription.Builder()
                .alt("Sign-In").type(com.hp.lft.sdk.web.ImageType.BUTTON).tagName("INPUT").build()).click();


        browser.close();



        //AppModel myModel = new AppModel(browser);

        //myModel.WelcomeMercuryToursPage().UserName().setValue("Amir");
        //myModel.WelcomeMercuryToursPage().Password().setValue("hpe");
        //myModel.WelcomeMercuryToursPage().Login().click();


    }



}
```

My POM.XML looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>lean.testing</groupId>
  <artifactId>leantesting</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>leantest</name>
  <description>leantesting project</description>
     <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>4.12</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hp.lft</groupId>
        <artifactId>unittesting</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.0</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hp.lft</groupId>
        <artifactId>sdk</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.0</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hp.lft</groupId>
        <artifactId>report</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.0</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hp.lft</groupId>
        <artifactId>reportbuilder</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.0</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
     </dependencies>
     <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <type>maven-plugin</type>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-common</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire-booter</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
     </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Effective POM.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>lean.testing</groupId>
  <artifactId>leantesting</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>leantest</name>
  <description>leantesting project</description>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-booter</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.hp.lft</groupId>
      <artifactId>unittesting</artifactId>
      <version>14.0.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.hp.lft</groupId>
      <artifactId>sdk</artifactId>
      <version>14.0.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.hp.lft</groupId>
      <artifactId>report</artifactId>
      <version>14.0.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.hp.lft</groupId>
      <artifactId>reportbuilder</artifactId>
      <version>14.0.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\src\test\resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\target</directory>
    <finalName>leantesting-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

I have no clue why from eclipse using maven test is passing, the log looks like (in eclipse):

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building leantest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ leantesting ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ leantesting ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ leantesting ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ leantesting ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ leantesting ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running leantesting.LeanFtTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 31.443 sec
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"

Results :

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 33.583 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-22T09:02:23+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/368M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"
```

In Jenkins it looks like:

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Maven-LeanFT-TestCompile-eclipse
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 64573
[leantesting] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\/bin/java" -Xms256m -Xmx512m -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-agent-1.8.1.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software\apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software\apache-maven-3.3.9/conf/logging" jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main "C:\Program Files\Apache Software\apache-maven-3.3.9" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.4.1.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-interceptor-1.8.1.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.8.1.jar" 64573
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\pom.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Maven-LeanFT-TestCompile-eclipse\.repository install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building leantest 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ leantesting ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ leantesting ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ leantesting ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ leantesting ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ leantesting ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running leantesting.LeanFtTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.301 sec <<< FAILURE!
leantesting.LeanFtTest  Time elapsed: 0.3 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at com.hp.lft.common.WindowsOSHelper.getCurrentSessionId(WindowsOSHelper.java:243)
    at com.hp.lft.common.OSHelperBase.getProcessesByName(OSHelperBase.java:12)
    at com.hp.lft.common.OSHelperBase.getRuntimeProcesses(OSHelperBase.java:17)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.ServerLauncher.launchIfNeeded(ServerLauncher.java:30)
    at com.hp.lft.unittesting.UnitTestBase.initSDK(UnitTestBase.java:184)
    at com.hp.lft.unittesting.UnitTestBase.init(UnitTestBase.java:176)
    at com.hp.lft.unittesting.UnitTestBase.classSetup(UnitTestBase.java:50)
    at unittesting.UnitTestClassBase.globalSetup(UnitTestClassBase.java:19)
    at leantesting.LeanFtTest.setUpBeforeClass(LeanFtTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

leantesting.LeanFtTest  Time elapsed: 0.301 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hp.lft.report.DefaultReporter.closeAllReportLevels(DefaultReporter.java:177)
    at com.hp.lft.unittesting.UnitTestBase.closeReportLevels(UnitTestBase.java:172)
    at com.hp.lft.unittesting.UnitTestBase.classTearDown(UnitTestBase.java:65)
    at unittesting.UnitTestClassBase.globalTearDown(UnitTestClassBase.java:33)
    at leantesting.LeanFtTest.tearDownAfterClass(LeanFtTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"

Results :

Tests in error: 
  leantesting.LeanFtTest: Index: 0, Size: 0
  leantesting.LeanFtTest

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0

[ERROR] There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ leantesting ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ leantesting ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\target\leantesting-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Maven-LeanFT-TestCompile-eclipse\.repository\lean\testing\leantesting\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\leantesting-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\pom.xml to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Maven-LeanFT-TestCompile-eclipse\.repository\lean\testing\leantesting\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\leantesting-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.417 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-22T09:15:42+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/325M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\pom.xml to lean.testing/leantesting/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/leantesting-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\khanami\workspace\leantesting\target\leantesting-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to lean.testing/leantesting/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/leantesting-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
channel stopped
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

Please help :(.

Cheers,
Amir

Comment: can you verify that your Jenkins env and local are the same.
java version ? mvn version ? settings.xml file ?

Comment: jenkins is running on local machine. thats the weird thing. in eclipse using maven tests pass. in jenkins using maven test fails. What is meant by settings.xml, sorry i never worked with Maven before.

Comment: run mvn with debug add -X to have some more info.

BTW any idea why the tests failed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!
Jenkins service under windows was running under system local account. i changed it to run under my userprofile.